# Enforcing trait implemented only on given type size in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-embedded

For embedded/IO use case in Rust, I need to build a lib to receive/transmit messages using a small fixed size buffer (must not exceed it). The messages themselves will be defined by the user of the lib.

Is there a way to define a Rust trait or a generic constraint to ensure that each user message is `#[repr(c,packed)]` and has a specific size? Or am I approaching it wrong?

```rust
// "global" data, per ISO specification must have <= 10 bytes
type BufferData = [u8; 10];
global_buffer: BufferData

// A user would define these messages that must fit in 10B

// This message 
#[repr(c, packed)]
struct MessageA {
  pub message_id: u8,
  pub some_flag: u8,
  pub some_data: [u8; 2],
  _padding: [u8; 6], // msg uses 4 bytes, so must have padding
}

#[repr(c, packed)]
struct MessageB {  // uses the whole 10 bytes, no padding
  pub message_id: u8,
  pub some_data: [u8; 9],
}
```

Elsewhere in code, I fill out these messages and transmute them (I might be using unsafe incorrectly here?):

```rust
{
  let ptr = &mut global_buffer;
  let msg = unsafe { &mut *(ptr as *mut BufferData as *mut MessageB) };
  *msg = MessageB { message_id = 0x1, some_flag = 0x10, ... };
}
transmit_buffer(&global_buffer);
```

Comment: Can you use nightly?

Comment: if possible - i would rather not, but i would certainly want to know of a feature that might become available in the future, so please do tell :)

Comment: There is a possibility using `generic_const_exprs`, but it will not become available in the near future.

Comment: You could also make users implement this trait themselves and mark it as `unsafe`.

Comment: they would have to implement it themselves, but I wonder if there is any compiler help available... `generic_const_exprs` might help, but not yet stable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do exactly that, but instead you can just before the unsafe code that assumes the type is of certain size, call a function that will fail at compile-time if the size is not as expected:

```rust
#[inline(always)]
const fn verify_size<T, const EXPECTED_SIZE: usize>() {
    struct Foo<T, const EXPECTED_SIZE: usize>(T);
    impl<T, const EXPECTED_SIZE: usize> Foo<T, EXPECTED_SIZE> {
        const VERIFY: () = if core::mem::size_of::<T>() != EXPECTED_SIZE {
            panic!("invalid size");
        };
    }
    
    Foo::<T, EXPECTED_SIZE>::VERIFY
}

fn assume_size_unsafe<T>() {
    verify_size::<T, 4>();
    
    unsafe {
        // ... do unsafe work assuming size_of::<T>() is 4 bytes
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks!  A side question - do you think my approach to serialize is good overall? Or some other method exist that doesn't have much perf cost

Comment: @YuriAstrakhan You need to use `[MaybeUninit<u8>; 10]`, because the type may have padding bytes. Other than that looks fine to me.